# Duplicated data using onSnapshot() with Firestore in ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i need some help. When i'm using onSnapshot function with Firestore, displayed data are duplicated. I understand the reason of that, i tryed to clear clear the array after the function but it didn't help. How can i fix it?

Here there is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setFavoritesData([]);
  setBranch([]);
  if (favorites.length==0){
    setNo(true);
  } else {
    setNo(false);
    setFavoritesData([]);
    favorites.map(link => {
      db.doc(link).get().then(data => {
        setFavoritesData(all => [...all, data.data()]); 
        setBranch(br => [...br, link]);
      });
    });
  }
}, [favorites]);

const query = () => {
    setFavorites([]);
    setBranch([]);
    setFavoritesData([]);
    const clientDoc = db.doc('Clients/' + id.toString());
    return (
        clientDoc.onSnapshot((client) => {
          setFavorites([]);
          setFavorites(client.data().Favourites);
        })
    )
}
```

Comment: What are `setFavoritesData` and `setFavorites` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand what you want to achieve with this code, maybe it would be easier if you explained the goal of your code. Anyway..

You should use the onSnapshot() inside the useEffect, and then you can clean the array once. The snapshot is now a collection, so you should map the collection and add the elements to the empty array.

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (favorites.length==0){
      setNo(true);
   } else {
      setNo(false);
      firebase.firestore()
      .collection(*your doc*)
      .onSnapshot( snapshot => {
          setFavorites([]);
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => 
              setFavorites(prevElements => [...prevElements, doc.data().Favourites]);
      }; 
   }
 }, [favorites]);
```